# MS Unit testing my MVC controller (returns JSON) from another solution

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

My Controller is on a separate solution

```
public partial class PrintController12 : MasterController
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Print/LabelPrint")]
    [ValidationResponseFilter]
    public IOldResponse SPrintRequest1([FromBody] PrintRequestData request)
    {
        return SPrintRequest(request);
    } 
 }
```

I wanted to Unit test, above controller, i tried this providing reference of above solution.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ParameterTest()
    {
        var controller = new PrintController12();
        IOldResponse  var = controller.SPrintRequest1([FromBody] PrintRequestData request);
    }
```

I face issue on 2nd line of my test method above, as it does not take argument=[FromBody] PrintRequestData request
,that i am passing here.

Answer (score 0):

You just need pass a `PrintRequestData` as a parameter:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ParameterTest()
{
    var controller = new PrintController12();
    PrintRequestData request = new PrintRequestData();
    IOldResponse  var = controller.SPrintRequest1(request);
}
```

The `[FromBody]` attribute is only to indicates to the MVC Framework binder how to retreive the parameters.

Comment: IOldResponse  var = controller.SPrintRequest1(request); here it (request) looks for request from initial solution. I am running initial solution (website) same time, and looking to pass request captured from (webpage).

Comment: I don't understand, it's a unit test ? So the purpose is to verify the good behavior of your controller.SPirintRequest1() method from different arguments. So you create differents scenarios to check all cases.

Comment: you are right, only thing I wanted to capture same string as running by first solution, so that I can assert here with a expected one [TestMethod]
public void ParameterTest()
{
    var controller = new PrintController12();
    solution1.PrintRequestData request = new solution1.PrintRequestData(); // This is from solution-1, web page running and on click of button, it capture request from web page
    IOldResponse  var = controller.SPrintRequest1(request); //but if i pass it here, it shows null, as a new request is getting created. I am looking for current request
}

Comment: Let me rephrase it, I want to capture, request already generated from controller (while another solution running same time), not a new request. New request will create blank.

Comment: So I think you need an another testing system. Unit tests are executed on a specific host without Web host. Perhaps a "Web Test" system (Selenium ?) would be a better approch, but don't know not well in this area.